# Wait for child process without freeing its resources

Tags: c, linux-kernel, fork, zombie-process

I am looking for a way to access the child's task_struct from the parent when the child is just about to end, or has just ended. The reason I don't want to use wait/waitpid is because after wait is finished, the task_struct and other things are freed.

Is there any way for the parent to wait for the child process to end without calling wait (so the task_struct can still be accessed from the zombie process)?
Any ideas what can be tried?

Comment: Its best if you give more information along with sample code on what you are trying to achieve. How are you accessing the `struct task_struct` ? What is stopping you from using `vfork()` to block the parent until the child returns.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `waitid(2)` with the `WNOWAIT` flag. Here's an excerpt from the manpage:

> WNOWAIT
>
> Leave the child in a waitable state; a later wait call can
>   be used to again retrieve the child status information.

So, something like this:

```
siginfo_t siginfo;
if (waitid(P_ALL, 0, &siginfo, WNOWAIT) < 0) {
    // Handle error...
} else {
    // PID of terminated child lives in siginfo.si_pid
}
```

This makes sure that the parent blocks until the child terminates, but it will still leave the child zombie laying around in the system.

If you want to wait for a specific child process with pid `X`, use `waitid(P_PID, X, &siginfo, WNOWAIT)`.

The child's exit status can be retrieved from `siginfo.si_status`. See `man waitid` to learn about the other fields in `siginfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [makelinux](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch03lev1sec1),

> **TASK_ZOMBIE** The task has terminated, but its parent has not yet issued
>   a `wait4()` system call. The task's process descriptor must remain in
>   case the parent wants to access it. If the parent calls wait4(), the
>   process descriptor is deallocated.

The process descriptor or your `task_struct` will persist even if your child has terminated until its parent has waited upon it. So, you can go ahead and access the child's `task_struct` just like you would have done if it were to be alive. The `task_struct` may be moved to a different kernel queue, though. Something like, a terminated queue instead of the running or ready queue

Also, if you want to notified of your child's death and do not want to block in a `waitid` with `WNOWAIT` set, you can set up a signal handler for [SIGCHLD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-4750/signals-7/index.html)